# Hardcode Domain Name in PS Script

Tags: powershell

**This script will prompt user to enter domain/username.
Is there a way to hardcode my domain? So user no need to write the domain.**

```
function Test-ADCrential{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [pscredential]$Credential
)
 
try {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
    if(!$Credential) {
        $Credential = Get-Credential -EA Stop
    }

    if($Credential.username.split("\").count -ne 2) {
        throw "You haven't entered credentials in DOMAIN\USERNAME format. Given value : $($Credential.Username)"
    }

    $DomainName = $Credential.username.Split("\")[0]
    $UserName = $Credential.username.Split("\")[1]
    $Password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password


    $PC = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, $DomainName)

    if($PC.ValidateCredentials($UserName,$Password)) {
        Write-Host "Credential validation successful for $($Credential.Username)"
        return $True
    } else {
        throw "Credential validation failed for $($Credential.Username)"
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error occurred while performing credential validation. $_"
    return $False
}
```

}

Test-ADCrential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Split the username into domain name and mere username, assuming
# 'Domain\User' format
$domainName, $userName = $Credential.Username -split '\\' # Split by literal '\'

if (-not $userName) {  # No domain part was specified, just a username.
  $userName = $domainName
  $domainName = $env:USERDOMAIN # Use the logon domain.
}
```

Comment: thanks man, its working. for my case i just replace the $env:USERDOMAIN with hardcode domain. cool

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Pro.

Answer (score 0):

You could populate with the current user:

```
Get-Credential -Credential $([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)
```

You can just pass the domain, but the focus starts on the password.